# How to make array on my object/class in vb?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, object

I'm trying to create an array of objects, but I keep running into errors and I'm hoping someone can explain, what I'm doing wrong in my code.

```
Friend Class myPosition
    Friend x1 As Integer
    Friend y1 As Integer
    Friend x2 As Integer
    Friend y2 As Integer
End Class

Dim product(,) As myPosition

For product_y = 0 To max_product_y - 1
    For product_x = 0 To max_product_x - 1

        product(product_y, product_x).x1 = 1     
        product(product_y, product_x).y1 = 2
        product(product_y, product_x).x2 = 3
        product(product_y, product_x).y2 = 4

   Next product_x
Next product_y
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm

Comment: <b>change izdelek_risba to product</b> sorry typing error

Comment: You can [edit] your question

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the error messages you get. Anyway, you have to initialize your array `product` before you use it.

Comment: indeed.. thats the error:  you have to initialize your array product before you use it

Comment: dont put html literals in posts, just enter a new line where you want them, but do learn to format code as code

Comment: And with that you give google a visit with the exact error message and get hundreds of result how to fix it. C´mon....

Comment: I voted to close, as this should have been easily searched and found on Google.

Comment: Sorry Plutonix... first time asking for help on this forum...

Comment: Yup, thats why there is a bunch of help on the edit screen and why they asked you to read [Ask] and take the [tour] when you signed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is initialized. You need to initialize the array (specify a size) and all object in that array.

```
Friend Class myPosition
    Friend x1 As Integer
    Friend y1 As Integer
    Friend x2 As Integer
    Friend y2 As Integer
End Class

    Dim max_product_y = 10
    Dim max_product_x = 3

    ' Initialize array, specify the size of each dimension
    Dim product(max_product_y, max_product_x) As myPosition

    For product_y = 0 To max_product_y - 1
        For product_x = 0 To max_product_x - 1
            ' Initialize the object
            product(product_y, product_x) = New myPosition

            product(product_y, product_x).x1 = 1
            product(product_y, product_x).y1 = 2
            product(product_y, product_x).x2 = 3
            product(product_y, product_x).y2 = 4

        Next product_x
    Next product_y
```

Comment: Thanks, the_lotus... "product(product_y, product_x) = New myPosition" saved my time...

Comment: @MirkoTipka If so, then the thing to do is to click the checkmark - that's how to say "thanks" here.  If you are going to participate here, you *really* ought to take the [Tour] and learn how SO works.  Accepting answers and (later) upvoting posts you find helpful or informative helps other users find good answers.

Comment: Thank you for tips and help, Plutonix. I will take tour one more time... slowly :-)